# Token Based Authentication (TBA) - OAuth - Netsuite - rest web services - Invalid Login Attempt

Tags: rest, web-services, oauth-2.0, netsuite

I have been trying to perform a token based authentication (TBA) with netsuite, but keep getting "Invalid Login Attempt"

I tried to refer to this also:
[How to request Netsuite RESTlet with TBA authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537757/how-to-request-netsuite-restlet-with-tba-authentification)

And I tried it both on

python:

https://gist.github.com/axilaris/6ecc58e43895dba17ce0ca1b8ce25d9a
(please check the code and response error)
it was mainly based on https://www.techfino.com/hubfs/Techfino_March2018/Images/Token-Based-Authentication-Guide-for-NetSuite.pdf

and

postman:

[image]

[image]

Here are my netsuite configuration for the permissions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe you may be better off trying to test this with Postman to build the OAuth framework and see where the issue is.
Secondly, from the backend logs for Netsuite, check what is the actual error which is manifesting as "Invalid login".

Comment: Are the parameters like account Id etc being passed correctly?For eg: is the account id coming in different case than what it actually is?

Comment: I am not exactly aware of NS related details but trying to debug this from a general OAuth related perspective. https://chamilelle.medium.com/setup-rest-web-service-and-oauth-2-0-in-your-netsuite-account-c4243240bc3f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try switching from HMAC-SHA1 to HMAC-SHA256 for your signature method. NetSuite is ending support for SHA1 and I already had an issue with it once.

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly - success - https://i.imgur.com/mu9UOyw.png (see the screenshot from AuditTrail). Here is the output response - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/axilaris/96178b77917ce0c6e1d477fc965d0b50/raw/c40183155131d4811755c2d25d2ebda6ac055355/gistfile1.txt

Comment: do you think you could provide guidance for the next step on how to make a query to Netsuite ? An example or a guide/doc somewhere ? Thanks @nick

Comment: It honestly looks like you are basically there, you've successfully queried Netsuite!
Now pass whatever parameters you need in your Oauth request to whatever RESTlet your calling, do whatever processing you'd like in your RESTlet and return the results as JSON back to your python program.
Just search 'NScriptType restlet' into GitHub and change search type to code if you more examples.

Answer (score 8):

"Invalid login attempt" is a generic error thrown by NetSuite when there's something misconfigured in the authentication headers. The best way to troubleshoot this is to use the "Login Audit Trail" search. From there, you should be able to troubleshoot what went wrong with your parameters. It could be that you entered an extra character or blank space into one of your tokens or you’re not generating a new timestamp or nonce.

Follow these steps:

- Go to Setup > Users/Roles > User Management > View Login Audit Trail.
- Check the Use Advanced Search box.
- Click the Results subtab.
- Add the following fields: Detail, Token-based Access Token Name,  and Token-based Application Name.
- Application Name.
- Click Submit.
- The Detail column displays error messages for any token-based authentication logins with a status of Failure.

After carefully debugging I found out that timestamps for generating request token are taking more time. I changed the time offset with my standard time zone. After syncing time, it worked for me. So even token definitions in NetSuite don't expire, timestamps for generating request tokens must be in time-window with time in the NetSuite environment.

Also Check these points:

- Doesn't have the Web Services Only Role checked.
- Check that your related integration has the TOKEN-BASED AUTHENTICATION checked.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the "Advanced Search", I had used the Login Audit Trail and found that it didn't provide enough detail.